# Putting comma(,) at end of array.Is it a convention?

Tags: php, arrays

Sometimes I see arrays like the following:

```
array('item1' => array(
         'subitem1',
         'subitem2',
      )
```

Why a comma is added at end of array wheras there is not any element after submitem2?

Comment: I was wondering, doesn't that make it include a null value (the last item)? I don't know since I'm always using this "correctly".

Comment: @Christian: not in PHP (it's positively encouraged in PHP). However, you should **never** include an additional comma in JavaScript. It is a syntax error in the Array constructor but is permitted in an Array literal. BUT, some browsers (read Internet Explorer) creates an additional element that is `undefined`.

Comment: In the description OP asks why a comma is added.
However, in the title OP asks: is it a convention, and that is not answered yet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It makes it easier to append another entry at a later point in time.

Comment: As a side-effect, wth version control software, the last line does not appear to be changed by adding a comma.

Comment: @Hamid: It is the *only* reason I use it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it.. could anyone explain it in a little more detail? How and why does it make it easier?  thnx..

Comment: If I want to e.g. rearrange items in the array declaration, or duplicate them, or copy-and-paste from another declaration, or auto-generate the source code, it's much easier if one doesn't have to worry about a special-case for the last entry.

Comment: This makes a lot of visual pollution to not change the greatness of a committer

Answer (score 1):

The comma is not needed at all. But you will still find some interpreters/compilers still allowing to use it. You can think of it this way: the interpreters is allowing you to make little mistakes and wisely fixing it internally. This is just a user-friendly way. Nothing else at all.

And you should not use that extra comma because a lot of strict ones will not let you pass through! Like Internet Explorer while interpreting Javascript. But Firefox will allow it.

Comment: One problem with PHP is that there's no formal grammar specification, just the *de facto* reference implementation.

Comment: yes...there are more languages...like javascript...so it's better to follow a good pattern! Don't know why I got a negative feedback here. Probably I am too confusing on expressing theories :p